# Generate clients for apis with @Hidden annotations via openapi-generator

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I'm using `swaggerCodegen` to generate Apis clients for a Spring based application using `org.openapitools.openapi-generator-cli`. I marked some operations with `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Hidden`. Swagger codegen is not generating client stubs for these. Is there a config to hide them in the Swagger documentation, but still generate client code?

Comment: Can you please provide a bit of your OAS json/yml?  Which generator are you using (java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud)?  How did you mark the operations with `Hidden` (edit the generated file, via CLI , etc)?  What are you expecting vs what are you getting (code examples)?  A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful in understanding the problem and intent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm using the codegen with language=spring & library=spring-cloud. @Hidden annotation is used in the Spring REST controller on the api operation. What I noticed is this stopped it from being included in the swagger.json that's the input for the codegen.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is the apis marked with @Hidden shouldn't be accessible via Swagger UI, but need to be available via SDK generated via the codegen client. I'm wondering if that's possible via some config

Comment: Are you using a generator such as `springdoc` or `springfox` to generate a json from existing apis, and then attempting to use the generated json to generate new apis/models?

Comment: using the org.springdoc:springdoc-openui-ui to generate the swagger.json

Comment: and this swagger.json in the input for the org.openapitools.openapi-generator-cli